# KSH Shell script not zipping up files

Tags: linux, unix, zip, ksh

I have a Korn shell script that is supposed to zip up files and it is not working properly in development. The same exact script works in production which is strange. We recently upgraded our Solaris Unix box to a Linux box in the development environment. So I am assuming that this may be the cause of the script not executing.

The pic below is shows the file list. The user will select a checkbox for the files they want to download and then they click the zip and download link and it should zip up those selected files and save it to your desktop. Unfortunately the zip folder is empty. Any ideas what the problem may be?

[image]

Here is the code below that zips up the files. Any idea why this Korn shell script works in development but not in production?

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# Utility to zip up files in the configuration_aerodynamic_properties area.
# Script takes two arguments the directory and the file list.
# The file list is tab seperated.
# This script returns the zip file.
#
# $Log: vmdb_zip_files.sh,v $
# Revision 1.4  2014/10/21 19:53:31  wmorris1
# ASR 13563 - Change incorrect mime type text/text to text/plain.
#
# Revision 1.3  2012/04/30 18:46:03  wmorris1
# ASR 12774 - Fix SSL and IE issue found after going to SSL.
#
# Revision 1.2  2004/11/11 12:49:33  bmorris
# ASR 55414 - removed UNIX groups for zipped file.
#
# Revision 1.1  2004/10/18 20:10:32  bmorris
# Initial revision
#
#set -x
function error_message {
  echo "Content-Type: text/plain;"
  echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"download_error.txt\";"
  COMMAND="unix2dos"
  echo ""
  echo "$(${COMMAND}  <<-EOF
 Error: $1

 EOF
 )"
 }
 if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
   error_message "Insufficient arguments to $(basename $0)!"
   return 1
 fi
 CONTENT="application/x-zip-compressed"
# Parse the directory path.
# Internal Field Sep (IFS) empty, cause spaces in file names, directories are important
  IFS=""
FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH=$(echo "${1}" | tr -d '~\\')
# File lists are seperated by tabs, parse them
  IFS=$(echo "\t")
set -A FILE_LIST - ${2}
# Make each of the file parameters in the file list protected.
  let count=0
    while (( $count < ${#FILE_LIST[*]} )); do
      FILE_LIST[count]="\"${FILE_LIST[count]}\""
  let count="count +1"
done
# Reset the IFS to the default.
IFS=$(echo " \n\t")
if [[ -n $3 ]]; then
  WEB_FILENAME="$3"
fi
# Don't let the user download stuff.
if [[ "${1}" = *..* ]] || [[ "${1}" = *~* ]] || [[ "${2}" = *..* ]] ||   [[ "${2}" = *~* ]]; then
 error_message "Path ${1}/${2} violates security."
 return 1
elif [[ ! -f ${FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH} ]] && [[ ! -d   ${FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH} ]]; then
 error_message "${FULL_FILE_PATH} does not exist or is not regular."
 return 1
elif [[ ! -r ${FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH} ]]; then
 error_message "${FULL_FILE_PATH} is not readable from the web."
 return 1
fi
# Zip up the f
COMMAND="cd \"${FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH}\"; zip -rX - ${FILE_LIST[*]}"
echo "Content-Type: ${CONTENT};"
if [[ -z  $HTTP_USER_AGENT || $HTTP_USER_AGENT != *MSIE* ]]; then
# IE Can't handle ssl and zip files
 echo "Pragma:no-cache"
fi
echo ""
eval "$COMMAND"
```

@meuh I removed the `-` in the `set -A FILE_LIST -`, here are the results of the error logs from our server. What does this mean because the txt files that I selected to zip and download to my desktop are still not saving to the zip folder. Here are the results below:

```
Hello Chris: cat vmdb_zip_files_8862.err
+ [ 3 -lt 2 ]
+ CONTENT=application/x-zip-compressed
+ IFS=''
+ tr -d '~\\'
+ echo /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export
+ FULL_DIRECTORY_PATH=/isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export
+ printf '\t'
+ IFS=$'\t'
+ set -A FILE_LIST flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt flight_dependent_data_443949.txt
+ let count=0
+ (( 0 < 2 ))
+ FILE_LIST[0]='"flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt"'
+ let count='count +1'
+ (( 1 < 2 ))
+ FILE_LIST[1]='"flight_dependent_data_443949.txt"'
+ let count='count +1'
+ (( 2 < 2 ))
+ echo ' \n\t'
+ IFS=' \n\t'
+ [[ -n power_export.zip ]]
+ WEB_FILENAME=power_export.zip
+ [[ /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export == *..* ]]
+ [[ /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export == *~* ]]
+ [[ $'flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt\tflight_dependent_data_443949.txt' == *..* ]]
+ [[ $'flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt\tflight_dependent_data_443949.txt' == *~* ]]
+ [[ ! -f /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export ]]
+ [[ ! -d /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export ]]
+ [[ ! -r /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export ]]
+ COMMAND='cd "/isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export"; zip -rX - "flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt" "flight_dependent_data_443949.txt"'
+ echo 'Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed;'
+ [[ -z 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko' ]]
+ [[ 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko' != *MSIE* ]]
+ echo Pragma:no-cache
+ echo ''
+ eval 'cd "/isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export"; zip -rX - "flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt" "flight_dependent_data_443949.txt"'
+ cd /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export
+ zip -rX - flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt flight_dependent_data_443949.txt
eval: zip: cannot execute [Exec format error]
```

Comment: The ksh on my Linux does not echo a tab char with `echo "\t"`. Perhaps you can replace this with the more portable `printf "%b" '\t'`

Comment: Ok I tried that and the file list is now outputting correctly but the zip folder is still empty when it is opened.

Comment: If your filename contains spaces, you might want to use ${FILE_LIST[@]} in your zip command instead.

Comment: The file names do not contain spaces. Anything else you think I should try?

Comment: If you really receive a zip file with no contents then perhaps the files are not readable to zip. If you run zip with no filenames it would exit in error and you would not get an empty zip file.  Check the error logs of your server. Note in your usage of: `set -A FILE_LIST -`. This is marked as obsolete by the ksh man page. Remove that `-` as it is cancelling the `set -x` that you could use to get more debug on stderr. Add `exec 2>/tmp/myfile` near the start of the script and look in that file for the debug.

Comment: @meuh can you take a look at the output of my error logs from our server, I added the results above. What do you think this means? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The `exec format error` suggests that the zip program found in the PATH is probably a binary compiled for Solaris. If you type `command -v zip` it should print something like `/usr/bin/zip` if it has been installed from a package.

Comment: @meuh what exactly do I need to do if the PATH is a binary compiled for Solaris? Since we are on a Linux box now do I need to change something? When I type the `command -v zip` I get this result `/oraloc/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/zip` is this incorrect? Do I need to install something to get zip to work correctly on this Linux box?

Comment: I dont know anything about your system, or what /oraloc is for, nor why it contains a zip binary, nor why it is in your PATH. Linux comes in many different distributions, debian, fedora, ubuntu, arch, ... but I imagine they all provide a *package* that includes the zip command appropriate for the system. You probably need to start asking questions on unix.stackexchange.com if you are not familiar with this.

Comment: First try calling zip with one isolated file, no script.

Comment: @WalterA I tried that, the zip command works fine when I don't use a script. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try from one command and include more until you find the line that will cause the error. Your `zip` works, so try ` cd /isweb/www/ss/issapt/vmdb/data_downloads/power_export; zip -rX - flight_dependent_heater_data_443949.txt flight_dependent_data_443949.txt` and when that works try it with `eval`.